# Update chrome.storage if extension's file changes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, auto-update, file-management, google-chrome-storage

I have a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/just-read/dgmanlpmmkibanfdgjocnabmcaclkmod) that uses `chrome.storage` to keep track of stylesheets to apply to the page's content. One of these stylesheets is a required default stylesheet that I initially load from Chrome's extension files if the file does not exist in the user's `chrome.storage`. This works great.

However, I sometimes update this default stylesheet with different rules to improve the styling. When the extension runs, it checks if the default stylsheet is there and finds the old version of the stylesheet - so it doesn't load anything from the extension's storage. Thus the user is still using the old version of the stylesheet.

On my local computer, I can manually empty out my `chrome.storage` and load the new one, but I can't do this through the extension when it's published because I don't want to empty it every time my extension runs nor do I know only the times the stylesheet has been updated in Chrome's extension files to do so.

I could get around this by checking each character of both files, comparing if they're the same, and loading the extension's stylesheet if so, but this seems like overkill and prone to errors.

**Is there an easier way to update `chrome.storage`'s stylesheet only when the extension's stylesheet is updated without changing the file name?**

If you want to look at my implementation, the whole project is open source [on GitHub](https://github.com/ZachSaucier/Just-Read).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a [nudge from Florian in a chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28856168#28856168), I came up with the following solution using a second `chrome.storage` space.

I was already checking to see if a stylesheet exists inside of the user's Chrome storage and loading the stylesheet from the extension's files if it didn't exist. To cause it to auto update upon changes, I now check a second `chrome.storage` space that holds a version number when checking whether or not to load the stylesheet from Chrome's storage. The basic approach is as follows:

```
// Helper function that checks whether an object is empty or not
function isEmpty(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length === 0;
}

var stylesheetObj = {}, // Keeps track of all stylesheets
    stylesheetVersion = 1; // THIS NUMBER MUST BE CHANGED FOR THE STYLESHEETS TO KNOW TO UPDATE

chrome.storage.sync.get('just-read-stylesheets', function (result) {
    // Here 'results' is an object with all stylesheets if it exists

    // This keeps track of whether or not the user has the latest stylsheet version
    var needsUpdate = false; 

    // Here I get the user's current stylesheet version
    chrome.storage.sync.get('stylesheet-version', function (versionResult) {

        // If the user has a version of the stylesheets and it is less than the cufrent one, update it
        if(isEmpty(versionResult) 
        || versionResult['stylesheet-version'] < stylesheetVersion) {

            chrome.storage.sync.set({'stylesheet-version': stylesheetVersion});

            needsUpdate = true;
        }

        if(isEmpty(result) // Not found, so we add our default
        || isEmpty(result["just-read-stylesheets"])
        || needsUpdate) { // Update the default stylesheet if it's on a previous version

            // Open the default CSS file and save it to our object
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', chrome.extension.getURL('default-styles.css'), true);
                // Code to handle successful GET here
            }
            xhr.send();
            return;
        }

        // Code to do if no load is necessary here
    });
});
```

This makes it so that the only thing that has to be changed to update the stylesheet for users is `stylesheetVersion`, making sure that it is larger than the previous versions. For example, if I updated the stylesheet and wanted the user's version to auto update, I would change `stylesheetVersion` from `1` to `1.1`.

If you need a more full implementation, you can find the JS file [here on GitHub](https://github.com/ZachSaucier/Just-Read/blob/master/content_script.js)

Answer (score -2):

Try to use  [`chrome.storage.sync`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) and add a listener to its `*onChanged*` event. Whenever anything changes in storage, that event fires. Here's sample code to listen for save changes:

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {
    for (key in changes) {
        var storageChange = changes[key];
        console.log('Storage key "%s" in namespace "%s" changed. ' +
        'Old value was "%s", new value is "%s".',
        key,
        namespace,
        storageChange.oldValue,
        storageChange.newValue);
    }
});
```

Comment: This listens to the chrome storage, but my problem is that I need to update chrome's storage when the *extension's* files are changed